# What is the problem of np.convolve with 10**9?

Tags: python, numpy, digits

Good morning, when I use the below code, I get a wrong result

```
import numpy as np
print(np.convolve([10**9], [ 10**9]))
```

I am getting:-1486618624 while I should be getting: (10 to the power of 9) * (10 to the power of 9) = (10 to the power of 18)

How can I overcome this problem?
It is very curious that I get the correct result by using:

```
print(np.convolve([10**10], [ 10**8]))
```

which gives me 1000000000000000000

while when I do:

```
print(np.convolve([10], [ 10**9]))
```

I get again a stupid result like 1410065408 rather than 10 to the power of 10. It looks like every time there is a 10 to the power of 9, I get strange results.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `10**9` is an integer, which in numpy is interpreted as an `int32`, that is a 32-bit integer. The maximal value that can be represented in that type is `2147483647`, if you go lager than that, you get an overflow. If you want to use integer types use `np.int64` instead, otherwise use floating point numbers e.g. `np.float`:

```
np.convolve(np.array([10**9], dtype=np.int64), np.array([10**9], dtype=np.int64))
```

Comment: Thanks. Then why does it work with 10**10? And how can I fix it?

Comment: If you use `10**10` it will create `int64` arrays from the start. Try it yourself: Print the `np.array([x]).dtype` for various values of `x`. Also check out the documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html